# C# Sockets: Automatically receiving messages

Tags: c#, sockets, client

I am rather new to C# and Sockets however I am trying my hand at making a kind of "chat" program. What I am having an issue with at the moment is making the client able to automatically receive a message from the server if one is available.

What I have tried so far:

```
System.Threading.Thread myThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new
    System.Threading.ThreadStart(listenThread));


public static void listenThread()
{
    while(true){
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.ReceiveLoop();
    }

}

private void ReceiveLoop()
{
    clientSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 100;
    byte[] receivedBuffer = new byte[1024];
    try
    {
        int rec = clientSocket.Receive(receivedBuffer);
        byte[] data = new byte[rec];
        Array.Copy(receivedBuffer, data, rec);
        updateClient("Received: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

ReceiveLoop() works when I access from the GUI thread, however it will not work(Throws SocketException, due to timeout) when accessed via myThread.

Any help or suggestions on another way I could approach this would be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: "it will not work". That's not much of a description of what's gone wrong. Error message? Line number?

Comment: 1a. Don't block the UI thread. 1b. Always make changes to the UI on the UI thread. 2a. Use StreamReader and StreamWriter. 2b. Use UTF8  instead of ASCII. 3.  Don't forget to close streams.

Comment: @spender Sorry, I was meant to say it throws a SocketException. E.G The socket times out.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM Sorry I dont really understand what you mean by don't block the UI thread. Also I invoke the UI thread when making changes, is that still not acceptable? My entire system is currently running on sockets, is streamreader and writer more effective?

Comment: 1. I you wait for a long time on the UI thread (listening maybe) the UI may freeze. 2. `Also I invoke the UI thread when making` yes that's the right way. 3. `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` can be used with sockets.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM Thanks for the suggestions, I will look into using StreamReader and StreamWriter. I am just lost as to why my solution does not work.